# Windows Batch file that opens powershell window as different user and enters python pipenv shell to execute commands

Tags: python, batch-file

I am attempting to write a batch script on a windows server that will take in user credentials, open a powershell window as that user (user has admin rights on this server), enter a Python pipenv shell to enter a virtual environment, and stay open to run various python commands.

So far all I've been able to do is make the Powershell window open and stay open. When I try to include arguments for username, password, and various commands the window will not stay open or show any indication that something's wrong.

```
@echo off


set /p username="Enter username: "
set directory="C:\path\to\directory\with\virtualenv"


runas /user:%username% "powershell.exe -noexit -command Set-Location %directory%; pipenv shell"
```

When this is executed the window pops open and immediately closes.

I don't have experience with batch scripts so I'm not sure what's going on.

Comment: Do NOT execute your Batch file via a double-click. Instead, open a cmd.exe command prompt window and enter the name of the Batch file. This way, any error message appears on the screen